# Error importing cert and key to Java keystore: keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect

Tags: java, openssl

I'm installing an application which requires Java (two supported versions - I've chosen the latest) and a cert signed by our internal CA.  When I try to import the key/cert into a Java keystore, I get a password error:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
```

#### Steps

I installed openssl:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)
```

I created a private key and a config file and used them to generate a CSR:

```
openssl genrsa -out .\server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key .\server.key -config .\server.cnf -out .\server.csr
```

I received the cert and merged the key and cert using a known password:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in '.\server.cer' -inkey .\server.key -out .\server.merged.pfx
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
```

I installed a version of Java supported by the application:

```
java --version
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

I attempt to create a new keystore and import the merged PFX file using the known password from the previous step:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore .\temporary.keystore -srckeystore .\server.merged.pfx -srcstoretype PKCS12
Importing keystore .\server.merged.pfx to .\temporary.keystore...
Enter source keystore password:
keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
```

The password was correct.  It was alphanumeric, both cases, no special characters, 30 characters long.

I'm sure I've done this before, some time ago, and it's worked.

Answer (score 5):

I realise it's a bit late, but maybe it helps somebody else.

Certain Java versions seem to have an issue with default cyphers and password hash algos in newer OpenSSL

I solved it by adding the following params to OpenSSL: `-certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -macalg sha1` so in your case, your command would become:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in '.\server.cer' -inkey .\server.key -out .\server.merged.pfx -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -macalg sha1
```